# ASP.NET MVC3 - Bug using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use Ajax.BeginForm() to POST A Json result from my controller (I'm using MVC3). When the Json result is called it should be sent to a javascript function and extract the object using

```
var myObject = content.get_response().get_object();
```

However it just throws a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method" when trying to invoke the Ajax POST.

**My code:**

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    return Json(new { Success = true, Message = message });
}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function JsonAdd_OnComplete(mycontext) {
            var myObject = mycontext.get_response().get_object();
            alert(mycontext.Message);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        @using(Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "JsonAdd_OnComplete" }))
        {
            @Html.TextBox("message")

            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The strange thing is that the exactly same code works in MVC2 - Is this a bug, or have I forgot something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know ASP but are you sure that `OnComplete = "JsonAdd_OnComplete"` shouldn't maybe be `OnComplete = JsonAdd_OnComplete` ??  In other words, don't quote the function name ...

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation it should be "FunctionName". - I've tried OnComplete = JsonAdd_OnComplete too, however it just returns a compile error because its not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC MS AJAX has been deprecated in favor of jQuery which is used by all `Ajax.*` helper methods. Javascript has become [unobtrusive](http://yobriefcase.posterous.com/unobtrusive-javascript-in-mvc3) as well. This means that you no longer have to call `.get_response().get_object()` but simply:

```
function JsonAdd_OnComplete(myObject) {
    // here myObject is already the JSON object 
    // as returned by the controller action
    alert(myObject.Message);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I gave that a shot when I wrote the code in my answer and it doesn't seem to work that way in the OnComplete method...assuming you use the old MicrosoftAjax methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `OnSuccess` method? When that method is called the object passed to it is a JSON object based on a JSONResult so you could do this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function JsonAdd_OnSuccess(mycontext) {
        alert(mycontext.Message);
    }
</script>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", 
    new AjaxOptions() { 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        OnSuccess = "JsonAdd_OnSuccess" })) {

    @Html.TextBox("message")

    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

}
```

In addition the OnComplete method returns an object that contains the following properties

```
context.responseText
context.responseBody
context.responseXml
```

You'll have to `eval()` the responseText to convert the text to JSON though.

Comment: I was soo hoping that your answer would work, but I get the following error when I do the `eval()`: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: @SerjSagan sounds like your json might be invalid.

Comment: The Json is being returned by the MVC Controller `JsonResult` with `return Json(new { result = true, inputs = mylist.ToList() });` See my answer to see how I got it to work...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the method provided by BuildStarted, here's how to structure the eval:

```
var json = eval("(" + context.responseText + ")");
```