# OnComplete Ajax.ActionLink parameter not Json in MVC 3?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC 3.  I have a method on the controller that returns a Json object, according to this question it should be returned to me as Json, but I am finding that is not the case:
[ASP.NET MVC3 - Bug using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539853/asp-net-mvc3-bug-using-javascript)

here's the code that I have:

```
function DeleteItem(obj) {
alert(obj.responseText);
alert(obj.Success);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
@Ajax.ActionLink("test", "Delete", "Home", new { id = "test" }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Delete?", HttpMethod = "Post", OnComplete = "DeleteItem" });
</body>
```

And the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
{
   return Json(new{Success = true,objectId = "testing"});
}
```

The first message box displays the response text which is:
{"Success":True, "objectId":"testing"}

the second message box displays undefined

So it is coming back to the client correctly, I'm just not sure how to get it out?

...Stefan

Answer (score 1):

The `Ajax.*` helpers never really worked nicely. Try using you using normal Html helpers with jquery:

```
@Html.ActionLink("test", "Delete", "Home", new { id = "test" }, new { id = "delete" })
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#delete').click(function() {
        if (confirm('Delete?')) {
            $.post(this.href, { }, function(result) {
                alert(result.Success);
            });    
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'd still love to find out how to get the Ajax.* helper to work, but your solution does work in the meantime.

Comment: probably i am probably lucky that never used any of Ajax.* helpers in mvc, but just wondering why they doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You could rebuild the object like this. It worked for me.

```
Json: {"message":"hello", "success": true}

function getJsonDetails_OnComplete(res) {

    var obj = eval("(" + res.responseText + ")");

    alert(obj.message);
};
```