# asp.net mvc3, how to get the value returned by JsonResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonresult

here's my action.

```
    public virtual JsonResult AddSearch()
    {
        var data = new { Id = food.Id, Image = food.Image, Name = food.Name};

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

here's my aJax form

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddSearch", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "AddSearch" }))
```

my javascript file.

```
    function AddSearch() {
        alert("sdfsdfsdf");
    }
```

it works, I see the alert box. my question is how I can get the "Id", "Name" and "Image" returned by JsonResult.  I tried

```
        alert("sdfsdfsdf");
```

it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC (to be precise unobtrusiveAjax helpers) will pass the standard [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`callback arguments to the `OnSuccess` method.

So you just need to add the parameters to your `AddSearch` method:

```
function AddSearch(data, status, xhr) {
        // you can access your properties from data
        alert(data.Name);
}
```

Comment: yes, your solution works, I also found answer here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539853/asp-net-mvc3-bug-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did... I accessed the list in my model and converted it to a JSON in my javascript.

```
var JsonServerList = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(@Model.ServerList) %>;
```

Now when i say ServerList[i].servername i get the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

In the controller:

```
public virtual JsonResult AddSearch()
{
    var data = new { Id = food.Id, Image = food.Image, Name = food.Name};

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the view/javascript section:

```
function AddSearch() {

    $.getJSON("@url.Action(here_goes_your_actionname)", { parameters }, function (data) {

        alert(data);

    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more property in AjaxOption "**UpdateTargetId**" where your response will append.
your View like

```
<div id="tagetId">
</div>

     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddSearch", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "AddSearch", UpdateTargetId = "tagetId" }))
     {

     }
```

In your Controller

```
public Actionresult  AddSearch()
{
    var data = new { Id = food.Id, Image = food.Image, Name = food.Name};

    return data;
}
```

you result will be Append in "targertId".